# GCE and conda envs, having problems to find packages installed with conda when running gce dev_server in windows

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv, conda

im using GCE with conda in windows.

I have a Virtualenv made with conda using the following command:

```
conda create --name myenv python=2.7.8
```

and then i installed a module that i want to use with my app called stripe

```
conda install --name myenv stripe
```

The problem is that when i run my GCE app launcher i get the following error:

```
import stripe

ImportError: No module named stripe
```

which is weird because i have my GCE app launcher pointing at `C:/Miniconda2/envs/myenv/pythonw.exe`

if i do:

```
activate myenv
```

and then i go into python and import stripe i get no problem, but when i run the launcher i get that error in the logs, this happens for all the packages i want to use.

this is what i get running `conda info -a`:

```
[myenv] C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\myenv\MyGCEApp>conda info -a
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Current conda install:

             platform : win-64
        conda version : 4.0.5
  conda-build version : 1.20.1
       python version : 2.7.11.final.0
     requests version : 2.9.1
     root environment : C:\Miniconda2  (writable)
  default environment : C:\Miniconda2\envs\myenv
     envs directories : C:\Miniconda2\envs
        package cache : C:\Miniconda2\pkgs
         channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False

# conda environments:
#
py27                     C:\Miniconda2\envs\py27
myenv               *  C:\Miniconda2\envs\myenv
work279                  C:\Miniconda2\envs\work279
root                     C:\Miniconda2

sys.version: 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (defa...
sys.prefix: C:\Miniconda2
sys.executable: C:\Miniconda2\python.exe
conda location: C:\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda
conda-build: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-build.exe
conda-convert: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-convert.exe
conda-develop: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-develop.exe
conda-env: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-env.exe
conda-index: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-index.exe
conda-inspect: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-inspect.exe
conda-metapackage: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-metapackage.exe
conda-pipbuild: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-pipbuild.exe
conda-server: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-server.exe
conda-sign: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-sign.exe
conda-skeleton: C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\conda-skeleton.exe
user site dirs: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27
                C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: C:\Miniconda2\envs\myenv
CONDA_ENVS_PATH: <not set>
PATH: C:\Miniconda2\Library\bin;C:\Miniconda2\envs\myenv;C:\Miniconda2\envs\myenv\Scripts;C:\Miniconda2\envs\myenv
\Library\bin;C:\Python279\;C:\Python279\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\tools\ruby21\bin;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\
Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth
 Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Mercurial;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\tools\python3;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WIND
OWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skyp
e\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Eng
ine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Prog
ramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\;C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\L
ocal\atom\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\tools\mysql\current\bin;C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\
nylas\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-clou
d-sdk\bin;C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\.meteor\;C:\Miniconda2\;C:\Miniconda2\Scripts
PYTHONHOME: <not set>
PYTHONPATH: <not set>

License directories:
    C:\Miniconda2\licenses
    C:\Users\MyUser\.continuum
    C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Continuum
License files (license*.txt):
Package/feature end dates:
```

Am i missing something?